# Restrictions.in in hibernate not giving more than 10 results back

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I am trying to get from a database a set of values by their uuids. When I try this using hibernate Restrictions.in(String field, Collection collection), it only returns 10 results.

```
public List<Player> getPlayersByUuid(List<String> playerUuids) {
    DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Player.class);
    criteria.add(Restrictions.in("playerUuid", playerUuids));
    return hibernateTemplate.findByCriteria(criteria);
}
```

However, if I create a list, getting every single item with individual operations I do get all of them.

```
public List<Player> getPlayersByUuid(List<String> playerUuids) {
    List<Player> players = new ArrayList<Player>();
    for (String playerUuid : playerUuids) {
        players.add(getPlayerByUuid(playerUuid));
    }
    return players;
}

public Player getPlayerByUuid(String playerUuid){           
    DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Player.class);
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("playerUuid", playerUuid));
    List<Player> players = hibernateTemplate.findByCriteria(criteria);
    if(players.size() == 0) {
        return null;
    } else if(players.size() == 1) {
        return players.get(0);
    } else {
        //return exception
        return null;
    }
}
```

Is there any kind of limit for Restrictions? If not, am I doing something wrong?

Thanks

Comment: There are no limits on Restrictions. Are you sure you are passing the same set of playerUuids while checking both approaches?

Comment: Absolutely. In fact the only change when trying one and the other is the three four lines of the method. It is curious that the value is 10 too. It looks like a default value somewhere...

Comment: My guess is that the HibernateTemplate has been configured to return 10 results maximum, using setMaxResults() (either in Java code or through XML configuration in the context XML file)

Comment: But in others parts of the code I have simple selects that return hundreds of results. It looks more as something related Restrictions.in criteria,